# How do I fix my text fields so that it doesn't overlap the panel beside it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working with a simple GUI and I'm having a hard time with my text fields.

[image]
This is what I'm working with. The one in the right is what it's supposed to look like, and the left one is what I did. I've successfully put the labels Address 1, Address 2, etc. But when I started putting the text fields, it disappeared. I tried using the setSize, setLocation, but nothing works.

The same thing is happening to the upper panel "Paymen Method", as seen in the expected outcome, there should be a text field. I have them in my codes but they're not showing up when being run. Help please.

Here's my codes:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class PanelDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 350;
    private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
    private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;
    public static void main(String[] args){
    //Frame
    JFrame contentPane = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    contentPane.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane.setSize(300,350);
    contentPane.setResizable(false);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //Payment Panel
    JPanel paymentPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    paymentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //paymentPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(270, 90));
    paymentPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Payment Method", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)));

    ////Components inside Payment Panel
    ////A) Panels: Radio and Details
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
    radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JRadioButton Rbutton1 = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
    JRadioButton Rbutton2 = new JRadioButton("E-Funds");
    JRadioButton Rbutton3 = new JRadioButton("Check");
    Rbutton3.setSelected(true);
    ButtonGroup Bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton1);
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton2);
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton3);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton1);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton2);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton3);

    //I thought of using a panel as a gap, but still didn't work
    /*JPanel gap = new JPanel();
    gap.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gap.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 90));*/


    JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
    detailsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    //detailsPanel
    JLabel Accountnum = new JLabel("Account number:");
    JTextField Account = new JTextField();
    Account.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 40));
    detailsPanel.add(Accountnum);
    detailsPanel.add(Account);

    paymentPanel.add(gap, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    paymentPanel.add(detailsPanel);
    paymentPanel.add(radioPanel);
    contentPane.add(paymentPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    ////Address Information Panel
    JPanel addressPanel = new JPanel();
    addressPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addressPanel.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(270, 80));
    addressPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Adress Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)));
    contentPane.add(addressPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    ////Components inside the Address Information Panel
    ////A) Labels (Address 1, Address 2,...)
    JPanel InfoLabel = new JPanel();
    InfoLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
    JLabel address1 = new JLabel("Address 1:");
    JLabel address2 = new JLabel("Address 2:");
    JLabel city = new JLabel("City:");
    JLabel state = new JLabel("State:");
    JLabel zip = new JLabel("Zip Code:");

    InfoLabel.add(address1);
    InfoLabel.add(address2);
    InfoLabel.add(city);
    InfoLabel.add(state);
    InfoLabel.add(zip);

    ////B)Text Fields
    JPanel infotext = new JPanel();
    infotext.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text3 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text4 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text5 = new JTextField();

    addressPanel.add(InfoLabel);
    addressPanel.add(infotext);

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(); 
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel test = new JLabel("test");
    controlPanel.add(test);
    contentPane.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


    contentPane.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit to get to a version that does what you need. Basically, all I did was cleaning the way you are using the layout managers. If you expect that you will have to do several such user interfaces then you could try to read the javadocs for the Swing layout managers in order to better understand them.

Here is the working version:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PanelDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
  private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 350;
  private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
  private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Frame
    JFrame contentPane = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    contentPane.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane.setSize(300, 350);
    contentPane.setResizable(false);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // Payment Panel
    JPanel paymentPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    paymentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // paymentPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(270, 90));
    paymentPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Payment Method",
        javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)));

    // //Components inside Payment Panel
    // //A) Panels: Radio and Details
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
    radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    JRadioButton Rbutton1 = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
    JRadioButton Rbutton2 = new JRadioButton("E-Funds");
    JRadioButton Rbutton3 = new JRadioButton("Check");
    Rbutton3.setSelected(true);
    ButtonGroup Bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton1);
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton2);
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton3);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton1);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton2);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton3);

    // I thought of using a panel as a gap, but still didn't work
    /*
     * JPanel gap = new JPanel(); gap.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     * gap.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 90));
     */

    JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
    detailsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    // detailsPanel
    JLabel Accountnum = new JLabel("Account number:");
    JTextField Account = new JTextField();
    Account.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 40));
    detailsPanel.add(Accountnum);
    detailsPanel.add(Account);

    // paymentPanel.add(gap, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    paymentPanel.add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    paymentPanel.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    contentPane.add(paymentPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    // //Address Information Panel
    JPanel addressPanel = new JPanel();
    addressPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addressPanel.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(270, 80));
    addressPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Adress Information",
        javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)));
    contentPane.add(addressPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // //Components inside the Address Information Panel
    // //A) Labels (Address 1, Address 2,...)
    JPanel InfoLabel = new JPanel();
    InfoLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
    JLabel address1 = new JLabel("Address 1:");
    JLabel address2 = new JLabel("Address 2:");
    JLabel city = new JLabel("City:");
    JLabel state = new JLabel("State:");
    JLabel zip = new JLabel("Zip Code:");
    JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text3 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text4 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text5 = new JTextField();

    InfoLabel.add(address1);
    InfoLabel.add(text1);
    InfoLabel.add(address2);
    InfoLabel.add(text2);
    InfoLabel.add(city);
    InfoLabel.add(text3);
    InfoLabel.add(state);
    InfoLabel.add(text4);
    InfoLabel.add(zip);
    InfoLabel.add(text5);

    // //B)Text Fields
    JPanel infotext = new JPanel();
    infotext.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));

    addressPanel.add(InfoLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//    addressPanel.add(infotext);

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel test = new JLabel("test");
    controlPanel.add(test);
    contentPane.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dan great work, a little explanation of what you did to get it to work would go along way to educating our OP ;)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot set region for layout.

```
paymentPanel.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
paymentPanel.add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

addressPanel.add(InfoLabel,BorderLayout.WEST); 
addressPanel.add(infotext, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be adjusted to this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class App extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 350;
   private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
   private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;
   public static void main(String[] args){
   //Frame
      JFrame contentPane = new javax.swing.JFrame();
      contentPane.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      contentPane.setSize(300,350);
      contentPane.setResizable(false);
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   //Payment Panel
      JPanel paymentPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
      paymentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      paymentPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Payment Method", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)));

      ////Components inside Payment Panel
      ////A) Panels: Radio and Details
      JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
      radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
      JRadioButton Rbutton1 = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
      JRadioButton Rbutton2 = new JRadioButton("E-Funds");
      JRadioButton Rbutton3 = new JRadioButton("Check");
      Rbutton3.setSelected(true);
      ButtonGroup Bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
      Bgroup.add(Rbutton1);
      Bgroup.add(Rbutton2);
      Bgroup.add(Rbutton3);
      radioPanel.add(Rbutton1);
      radioPanel.add(Rbutton2);
      radioPanel.add(Rbutton3);

      JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
      detailsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
//detailsPanel
      JLabel Accountnum = new JLabel("Account number:");
      JTextField Account = new JTextField();
      Account.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 40));
      detailsPanel.add(Accountnum);
      detailsPanel.add(Account);

      //paymentPanel.add(gap, BorderLayout.CENTER); // THIS PRODUCES SYNTAX ERROR
      paymentPanel.add(radioPanel);
      paymentPanel.add(detailsPanel);
      contentPane.add(paymentPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

////Address Information Panel
      JPanel addressPanel = new JPanel();
      addressPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      addressPanel.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(270, 80));
      addressPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Adress Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)));
      contentPane.add(addressPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

////Components inside the Address Information Panel
////A) Labels (Address 1, Address 2,...)
      JPanel InfoLabel = new JPanel();
      InfoLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
      JLabel address1 = new JLabel("Address 1:");
      JLabel address2 = new JLabel("Address 2:");
      JLabel city = new JLabel("City:");
      JLabel state = new JLabel("State:");
      JLabel zip = new JLabel("Zip Code:");

      InfoLabel.add(address1);
      InfoLabel.add(address2);
      InfoLabel.add(city);
      InfoLabel.add(state);
      InfoLabel.add(zip);

////B)Text Fields
      JPanel infotext = new JPanel();
      infotext.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

      JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
      JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
      JTextField text3 = new JTextField();
      JTextField text4 = new JTextField();
      JTextField text5 = new JTextField();

      infotext.add(text1);
      infotext.add(text2);
      infotext.add(text3);
      infotext.add(text4);
      infotext.add(text5);

      addressPanel.add(InfoLabel);
      addressPanel.add(infotext);

      JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(); 
      controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      JLabel test = new JLabel("test");
      controlPanel.add(test);
      contentPane.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


      contentPane.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Namely,

- you must remove the `paymentPanel.add(gap, BorderLayout.CENTER);` line, since it produces a syntax error
- you must specify `paymentPanel`, `addressPanel` to have a `GridLayout(1,2)`, in order for them to be able to contain the `radioPanel`, `detailsPanel`, `InfoLabel` and `infotext` panels in a non-overlapping way
- you must add the `radioPanel` in the `paymentPanel` *before* the `detailsPanel`
- you must actually add the text fields to the `infotext` panel, i.e. `infotext.add(text1);` etc.

**Note**: I know that by now you probably don't need this, but I wanted to write this answer since I don't really like @Dan's answer, who, for example, kept the `BorderLayout` in the `paymentpanel` and basically wrote his own version of the code, instead of modifying your code just enough so that it will work. Anyway.